# Zend Studio PHP Explorer doesn't show my New project

Tags: php, zend-studio

I'm new in Zend Studio, and a new developer of PHP.

Now, I have easy question, I have created a project in Zend Studio, New -> PHP Project but then the newly created project didn't show up in the PHP explorer mini window.

I changed the Directory to opt/lampp/htdocs/tutorial. Thats the fault, and I want to know how to change the directory and still show it in the PHP explorer.

Thanks!! :?

Comment: Is this the Eclipse-based Zend Studio?  6.0?

Answer (score 1):

You can import existing projects into your new workspace:

File->import->existing projects into workspace

Answer (score 0):

In the New PHP Project dialog, what option did you choose? "Create project from existing source" or "create new project in workspace"?
Go to Window -> Show View -> Other... -> General -> Project Explorer. In this new view do you still don't see the project?
Does it happen every time you create a new project?

Yossi Leon

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I had this issue recently, so wanted to share.

Assuming you have selected a working set either intentionally or inadvertently, and therefore you can only see projects that are part of that set.

In Zend Studio/Eclipse, click the down triangle on the far right of your Explorer pane, and select "Deselect Working Set" if not grayed out.  This will remove your working set configuration, and display all projects regardless of working set.